# Thingiverse dealer button text block

Tags: thingiverse

I’ve been using Thingiverse pretty heavily since I started printing, and I frequently come across the same text block in unrelated models. Am I missing the joke or a hidden meaning in the frequent reuse of the following content?

> Designed up this dealer button to use in home games or have just as something laying around for any poker fan. It was inspired by a dealer button in Pokerstars VR.
>
> Printing:
>
> Ring - Infil to add weight, supports needed for spade inset. Letter embossing doesn't need it.
> Spade - Infil to add weight, no supports
> Letters - Print flat, already scaled to fit nicely in the embossing
> Star - Infil to add weight.
>
> Full print with 4x4x4 walls/top/bottom and 38% infil came to about 48g in weight.
>
> Glue in lettering and spade. Star may need minor sanding but should push fit into the space tightly and not need anything else to secure it.

Here is an example of what I mean: [Voronoi bear](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4887617). Just curious if anyone knows why that’s used as a pseudo default description, or if I should avoid those files for any reason I’m unaware of.

Here’s another example: [cats](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4871879)

Comment: At first glance, I'd suggest someone pasted a block of text and submit it without due care. If this is appearing in other models, it's more difficult to make a conclusion. Is it the same user making these model-unrelated posts?

Comment: I see it across users, concepts, everywhere it’s weird. You can leave that section blank so it seems to be an intentional choice.

Comment: Maybe it's the result of some database corruption on their site? The site is basically unmaintained and has a lot of issues so it wouldn't surprise me if something like that happened.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about default text (or a bug) on a website.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's likely better suited for chat and otherwise unrelated to 3d printing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "dealer button" text is the default text that Thingiverse inserts when you create a new Thing entry.  If you get in a hurry and hit "Publish Thing" before you edit that, it'll go up for everyone to see with the "dealer button" default text still in place.  Many times, when you see that, you'll also see the defaults still in place for machine specs, filament type, etc.

In other words, it's just a user error, especially prevalent on "quickie" uploads that aren't intended for a wide audience or long term preservation.  Based on comments, this may also be a relatively recent change at Thingiverse; I've only uploaded designs there over the past few months, and I've seen it every time over that time frame (since about April 2021).

Comment: That was not the case when I last uploaded something to Thingiverse though, but I can reproduce it now. What an odd "feature".

Comment: @towe I agree, I guess someone decided obviously wrong text is better than a blank field (perhaps a blank field messes with their database some way).

Comment: Probably, but I'd have used the Lorem Ipsum or some "DESCRIBE YOUR CREATION HERE". Weird.

Comment: @towe Again, I agree -- but as noted elsewhere, Thingiverse is basically unmaintained...

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:
https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4888256

The text entered by the author is visible above the seemingly random text you mentioned in your question.

Seeing how Thingiverse is a Makerbot product, it's likely that they've messed up their database somehow.